# In Emacs, how to highlight newly added text automatically with 'highlight-regexp'?

Tags: emacs, highlighting

When I use 'highlight-regexp', highlighting is only applied to current text. So, the newly added text isn't highlighted at all, though it contains the same regular expression. How can the newly added text be highlighted automatically by 'highlight-regexp'?

[image: In this picture, I want 'keyword' in 3rd line to be highlighted automatically.]

Comment: Have you disabled font-lock-mode (or are using an old emacs)? Highlighting of newly added text should be automatic when font-lock-mode is being used, and in Emacs >= 22.1 it is enabled by default.

Comment: 'M-x emacs-version' shows me the version 25.1.50.2. The above picture is updated with the result of version-checking. And, font-lock-mode have been enabled as you expected.

Comment: Thanks guys. It works within downgraded version 24.3.1